# Consistent graph size in R using ggplot2 (legend and axis change the size)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a mostly cosmetic problem. I'm creating four plots using the ggplot2 library that I then arrange in one column (using [this](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Multiple%20graphs%20on%20one%20page%20(ggplot2)/)). The graphs display the same data but for four groups, the x-axis is time which is why I want to keep the graphs in one single column.

So I add the legend to the top graph, and the labels for the x-axis to the bottom graph. These two actions change the size of the graph; adding a legend causes the graph to grow, adding the x-axis labels causes it to shrink to accomodate these things.

Is there a way to specify a fixed graph size, that would make my layout consistent?

My plot:
[image: plot]

Code for reproducible results:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

raw_data <- structure(list(Sample = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L), Month = structure(c(12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 
10L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
12L, 12L), .Label = c("April", "Aug", "Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "July", 
"June", "March", "May", "Nov", "Oct", "Sep"), class = "factor"), 
    Channel = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B"), class = "factor"), Amplitude = c(5000L, 
    5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 
    5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 
    5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 
    5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L)), .Names = c("Sample", 
"Month", "Channel", "Amplitude"), row.names = c(NA, 52L), class = "data.frame")



multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, cols) {
    require(grid)

    # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
    plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

    numPlots = length(plots)

    # Make the panel
    plotCols = cols                          # Number of columns of plots
    plotRows = ceiling(numPlots/plotCols) # Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols

    # Set up the page
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(plotRows, plotCols)))
    vplayout <- function(x, y) {
            viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
    }

    # Make each plot, in the correct location
    for (i in 1:numPlots) {
        curRow = ceiling(i/plotCols)
        curCol = (i-1) %% plotCols + 1
        print(plots[[i]], vp = vplayout(curRow, curCol))
    }

}


mybarplot <- function(first=0, last=0) {
    # Create the barplot 
    p <- ggplot(raw_data, aes(x=Sample, y=Amplitude, fill=Channel))

    # Make it a grouped barplot with already summarised values
    p <- p +  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")


    # Apply a log10 transformation to the y-axis, and create appropriate axis ticks
    p <- p + scale_y_log10(breaks = c(5,10,50,100,500,1000,5000,10000))

    # Zoom in (barplots will not show when axis change to remove 0, so have to zoom)
    p <- p + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1,15000), xlim=c(1,26))

    # Make it greyscale
    p <- p + scale_fill_grey()


    # Hide X label
    p <- p + opts(axis.text.x=theme_blank(), axis.title.x=theme_blank(), axis.title.y=theme_blank())
    # Change X label size
    p <- p + opts(axis.text.y=theme_text(size=7))



    # Change the Legend
    p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "grey75", "grey25"), name="Channel", breaks=c("A", "B"))

    #margins
    # c(top,,bottom,)
    top_margin    <- unit(c(    1, 1, -0.25, 1), "lines")
    middle_margin <- unit(c(-0.25, 1, -0.25, 1), "lines")
    bottom_margin <- unit(c(-0.25, 1,     2, 1), "lines")


    if (first) {
        # Anchor legend box to top right corner
        p <- p + opts(legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(1,1))
        # Put a white box around it
        p <- p + opts(legend.background = theme_rect(fill="white"))
        # Top margin
        p <- p + opts(plot.margin = top_margin)
        p <- p + scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:26)
    } else {
        p <- p + opts(legend.position="none")
        if (last) {
            # Bottom margin
            p <- p + opts(plot.margin = bottom_margin)
                # label X-axis
            p <- p + scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:26, labels=c("Sep", "", "Oct", "", "Nov", "", "Dec", "", "Jan", "", "Feb", "", "March", "", "April", "", "May", "", "June", "", "July", "", "Aug", "", "Sep", ""))

            p <- p + ylab("Amplitude")
            p <- p + xlab("Sampling time")
            # Angle x labels
            #p <- p + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-45, hjust=0.5))
            p <- p + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(hjust=0.5))

            # Move X title
            p <- p + opts(axis.title.x=theme_text(vjust=-0.5))
        } else {
            p <- p + opts(plot.margin = middle_margin)
            p <- p + scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:26)
        }
    }



}


plot1 <- mybarplot(first=1)
plot2 <- mybarplot()
plot3 <- mybarplot()
plot4 <- mybarplot(last=1)

multiplot(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, cols=1)
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape_0.8.4 plyr_1.7.1    ggplot2_0.9.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-18        RColorBrewer_1.0-5 colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       labeling_0.1       memoise_0.1        munsell_0.3        proto_0.3-9.2      reshape2_1.2.1    
[11] scales_0.2.1       stringr_0.6.1
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to make the plot so that your question is [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry about that. Added code to reproduce it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example each plot is identical, however I assume that isn't the plan for your final product.  I think the easiest way to do this is with faceting rather than laying out each plot separately.

```
dat <- data.frame(facetvar=letters[1:5], yvar=rep(1:10, each=5), xvar=rep(letters[6:10], each=5))
ggplot(dat, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar, group=facetvar)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
    facet_grid(facetvar~.)
```

You can subset your data first if need be and use an arbitrary faceting variable.

```
ggplot(dat[sample(1:50, 40),], aes(x=xvar, y=yvar, group=facetvar)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
    facet_grid(facetvar~.)
```

You can also supply `scales.y='free'` to `facet_grid()` if needed.

Comment: Yeah, the data is identical in my example, but it won't be in the final graph. That was only because it was the fastest way to reproduce it. The size difference is still there. 

In order to use facets I need to have all my data in 1 frame, right? As it is now I get the data from 4 seperate files and I need to transpose and melt the data first. I'll look into doing it at work tomorrow, but I fear it will be tricky to consolidate them into one single dataframe.

Comment: You are correct, to facet you need a single `data.frame`.  However, after your melt steps you can often add an arbitrary "facet" column and use something like `rbind()` to mash them all together.

Comment: It shouldn't be tricky at all. Rename the response and predictor columns in the four datasets to the same values, add a column to each that gives the facet id (via `rep(ID, length(data))`, bind them, then replot using a facet statement

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. So that's that solved. Just gotta figure out the small things to make it look good.